# Chrome extension "Pesticide" doesn't work on local site that I am developing

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I am currently learning web development from a Udemy bootcamp 2021 and have a problem accessing one of the tools they are using to show borders on a website for styling. Its called "pesticide" (link below).

Problem is that this tool only shows those helpful borders on online websites "in the wild" while the local page I open to view doesn't have the borders.

I tried another tool like that (link below). and same effect. Online works. local doesn't.

Anyone know what might be at issue or of another tool if tool is the problem (although by logic it seems its me not the tools).

Using Chrome on Windows 10

Here is the problem recorded:
https://recordit.co/F8Nj9jqkoR

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome-with/neonnmencpneifkhlmhmfhfiklgjmloi

https://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Comment: https://github.com/mrmrs/pesticide/issues/59

Answer (score 11):

Just follow the following steps its worked for me...

Click on the Extension button > Pesticide > right click on 3 dots > Manage Extension > scroll down goto the > Allow access to file URLs click on the following image description link for understanding clearly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As MattHamer5 pointed out in the comments with that link, you can go to the Extensions tab by clicking on the `Extensions` button in the up-right corner and then on `Manage Extensions`, or by going to this URL: `chrome://extensions/`. There you should see all your extensions that you installed, so click on `Details` for the `Pesticide for Chrome (without hover bar)` window and check `Allow access to file URLs`. That should fix your problem.